# Provide a list of names with consecutive values in another column

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with company names and years:

```
2001  company 1
2002  company 1
2003  company 1
2004  company 1
2001  company 2
2002  company 2
2001  company 3
2003  company 3
2004  company 3
```

I need to write a function that will, given years n and m, provide me a list of companies which have corresponding consecutive year values beginning at year n and ending at year m.

For example, in the above case, f(2001, 2002) would show:

```
2001  company 1
2002  company 1
2001  company 2
2002  company 2
```

It could also provide only the company names.  f(2001, 2003) would show only companies 1 and 2 since company 3 skips 2002.

Comment: I do not understand why for `f(2001, 2003)` company2 should be in the result. (For company2 is no row with year 2003.) Can you please explain, i.e. edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also wrap a few `dplyr` functions into your function to get the desired results.

```
library(dplyr)

company_func <- function(data = data, year_1, year_2){
  #filter dataset to years of interest
  data <- data %>% filter(Year >= year_1 & Year <= year_2)
  #sort by company and year
  data <- data %>% arrange(Company, Year)
  #calc difference in years for each company
  data <- data %>% group_by(Company)
  %>% mutate("year_diff" = Year - lag(Year, default = min(Year)))
  #filter to only comp with consecutive years
  data.filter <- data %>% filter(year_diff == 1)
  data <- data %>% filter(Company %in% data.filter$Company) %>% 
    select(Company, Year)
  return(data)
}
```

The results:

`company_func(data, 2001, 2002)`

```
     Company Year
1  company 1 2001
2  company 1 2002
3  company 2 2001
4  company 2 2002
```

`company_func(data, 2001, 2003)`

```
     Company Year
1  company 1 2001
2  company 1 2002
3  company 1 2003
4  company 2 2001
5  company 2 2002
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
year1 = value of year1 (start year)
year2 = value of year2 (end year)
df = the data frame which has these values

companies_func <- function(year1, year2, df)
{
    return (df[(df$year >= year1) & (df$year <= year2)])
}

print(companies_func(2001, 2002, df))

   year  company
1: 2001 company1
2: 2002 company1
3: 2001 company2
4: 2002 company2
5: 2001 company3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Won't this still print if companies have skipped years inbetween n and m?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")

dt <- fread(
"year company
2001  company1
2002  company1
2003  company1
2004  company1
2001  company2
2002  company2
2001  company3
2003  company3
2004  company3")

years <- 2001:2002
dt[, if (all(years %in% year)) company, company][,1]
# dt[, if (all(years %in% year)) company, company][, company] # if you want a vector of char
```

This will give you the names of the companies which have the full sequence of years:

```
# > dt[, if (all(years %in% year)) company, company][,1]
#     company
# 1: company1
# 2: company2
```

If you want to define a function, you can do:

```
f <- function(DT, from, to) {
  years <- from:to
  DT[, if (all(years %in% year)) company, company][,1]
}

f(dt, 2001, 2002)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the data.table package instead of a function

```
years = c(2001, 2002) #vector with your years

dt <- as.data.table(df) #convert the table to a data.table

dt[year %in% years]
```

EDIT:

I misread your problem. If you want a range of years I would do it like this:

```
years = c(2001:2003) #vector with your years, with starting and endpoint

dt <- as.data.table(df) #convert the table to a data.table

dt[year %in% years]
```

Comment: Actually - I just tried this and while it works, it also shows companies who may not have the full span of years.  For example, if I let years = c(2001:2005), it gives me companies that may only have years from 2001 to 2003.  Is there a way to prevent this?